# Asp .net mvc session

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to get the projects names and description of the supervisor who is online

MY Supervisor Controller:

```
public ActionResult SupervisorDashboard()
{
    var message = TempData["message"] as string;
    var name = (from s in dc.Supervisors
            where s.sup_email == message
            select s.sup_fname).SingleOrDefault();
    ViewBag.username = name;
    return View();
}

public ActionResult ViewProject()
{
    var message = TempData["message"] as string;
    var name = (from s in dc.Supervisors
                where s.sup_email == message
                select s.sup_fname).SingleOrDefault();
    ViewBag.username = name;

    var supid= (from s in dc.Supervisors
                 where s.sup_email==message
                 select s.sup_ID).SingleOrDefault();

    var projectdata = (from s in dc.OfferedProjects
                    where s.FK_sup_ID==supid
                        select s);
    return View(projectdata);
}
```

My Supervisor Model:

```
public class SupervisorModel
{
    public Supervisor supervisor { get; set; }
    public OfferedProject offerproject { get; set; }
}
```

My View:

```
@model IEnumerable<FYPManagment.Models.SupervisorModel>
@using FYPManagment;
@{
    List<OfferedProject> projectdata = (List<OfferedProject>)ViewData["projectdata"];
    ViewBag.Title = "ViewProject";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_SupervisorDashboarLayout.cshtml";
}

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
    <td>@item.offerproject.proj_title</td>
    <td>@item.offerproject.proj_description</td>
    <td>
    <a href="#">Send Request</a>
    </td>

    </tr>
}
```

My Home Controller:

```
TempData["message"] = email;
//Session["user"] = email;
if (type == "supervisor")
{
    return RedirectToAction("SupervisorDashboard", "Supervisor");
}
```

My Supervisor Dashboard action is getting the email of the online user but same code in view project action is not working. I will be highly thankful for your precious time.

Comment: It would help if you formatted your code so it was legible, there is random indentation everywhere which makes it a PITA to read through (which is what you are expecting others to do). I have edited it for you this time.

Comment: Please post the code that does the redirect to `ViewProject`.

Answer (score 0):

You can only read the value of a key in TempData ONE TIME (hence the name 'temp'). it is removed once it is read. Change the use of TempData to ViewBag or session and it will work.

Comment: It is not removed once read.  It will survive until the end of processing the request.

Comment: each method returns an action result which is a complete 'request'. Once the first request reads it and returns view the data is removed so when you come into the second action it is gone.